# image hovering effect with text

Tags: css

I have few images with a title and a description. I want to put the title and description behind the image and when I hover on it, the image disappear and the title and the description appear.

I have already done few things, but I cannot go on.

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="views-field-field-contest-image">
  <a href=""> <img>....</img> </a>
</div>
<div class="views-field-title">
  <p>("title")</p>
</div>
<div class="views-field-field-description">
  <p>("description")</p>
</div>
```

and here is the css code:

```
.views-field-field-contest-image {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
}

.views-field-field-contest-image:hover img {
    display: none;
}

.views-field-title {
    display:none;
}

.views-field-field-description {
    display:none;
}

.views-field-title:hover {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20% 0 0;
}
```

The problem is that the title and the description  "hiding" under the image and not behind and I can't make them appear on hover

Comment: Can you not use the anchor links Id and then put a:hover display:none? And on the a just put display:block

Comment: can you add the container of this HTLM elements ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking for this <div class="view-content">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also play with positioning:

HTML

```
<div class="view-content">
    <div class="views-field-field-contest-image">
      <a href=""> <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/technics">....</img> </a>
    </div>

    <div class="views-field-title">
      <p>("title")</p>
    </div>

    <div class="views-field-field-description">
      <p>("description")</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.views-field-field-contest-image {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 250px;
}

.views-field-field-contest-image:hover img {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s;
    opacity: 0.2
}

.view-content{width: 250px; height: 250px; position: relative; }
.views-field-title, .views-field-field-description{ width: 250px; height: 250px; position: absolute; top: 0; z-index: -1; text-align: center; line-height: 1em;}
.views-field-field-description{ top: 1.5em; }
```

Comment: Thank you. This work perfect. Now I have only format the text and I finish it :)

Comment: Hello @Ghilas. I have a problem with the code. My content are load in a grid with 3 collumns. When I have only 3 items, I didn't have any problem, but know when a second row created all the titles and the descriptions show on the first row. Maybe the problem is with the top:0 but I couldn't handle to fix it.

Comment: Can you make an exemple of how the columns are structured ?

Comment: juste add this line: `.views-view-grid td{position: relative;}`

ps: you have to be able to touch your html code if you want to perfectly format the text

Comment: the line doesn't solve the problem :( I found a way to solve it with increasing the padding-top for each row, but I don't think that this is the best way

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the image as a background image, with the description/title in the `<a />` tag. On hover (over the whole div), hide the background image and show the components:

```
<style>
.views-field-field-contest-image {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: block;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  background-image: url("...");
}

.views-field-field-contest-image:hover  {
  background-image: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.views-field-title {
  display:none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20% 0 0;
}

.views-field-field-description {
  display:none;
}

.views-field-field-contest-image:hover .views-field-title,
.views-field-field-contest-image:hover .views-field-field-description 
{
  display: block;
}
</style>

<div class="views-field-field-contest-image">
  <a href="#">  
    <div class="views-field-title">
      <p>("title")</p>
    </div>
    <div class="views-field-field-description">
      <p>("description")</p>
    </div>  
  </a>
</div>
```

Example CodePen: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/pEwyq

Comment: The problem is that I am using drupal and I don't know how to change the html. I can only add CSS code.